# How to query users who have access to a particular record?

Tags: permissions, user, userrecordaccess, record-access-level

I have been going through the forums and the documentation and I do not find a way to query the Users who have access to a particular record.

For example, when I upload a document, a mail has to be sent to those Users who have access to that particular document. For this, I need the UserId.

The `UserRecordAccess` object doesn't allow us to query the UserIds. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around but it isn't the best of practices.

I put all the users who had access to a particular library in a public group. Then when I inserted a document into a library, I check the library by using its Id. Once I have the library, I query all the users of that particular group and take their email ids and mail a notification to them.

This isn't the best practice as I had to hard-code the ParentId in the Content Document to check the library the content was inserted in.

If someone can come up with a better solution, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `userRecordAccess` object to check `CRUD` permissions..

So pass the recordId and userId.. to check that user having what type of access on that record..

you can check variables like `HasDeleteAccess`. If `HasDeleteAccess` true means user have delete access. If false then user don't have access..

Based on these accessibility perform DML..

```
List<UserRecordAccess> lstUserRecordAccess = [SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess, 
                                                     HasDeleteAccess, 
                                                     HasEditAccess,
                                                     HasReadAccess, 
                                                     HasTransferAccess 
                                                FROM UserRecordAccess 
                                               WHERE UserId = '00550000000rlrX' 
                                                 AND RecordId = '0015000000TaWdI'];
```

---

Comment: nice answer. +1

Comment: Yes, but this is not my requirement. I have a record and I need the list of users who have access to it. How do I do this? In userRecordAccess, I can only see if the CRUD permissions are there for a given user but I cannot have the UserId in the query result

Comment: @User2529 then don't give userId in where condition instead query this field.

Comment: That's what I said. UserId cannot be given in the query result

Comment: @User2529 you have to specify useId in WHERE condition else you will get this error `Where clause must contain UserId = [single ID]`

Comment: I am understanding everything you guys are telling me but you are not able to understand what I'm trying to say.

When I query like this 
`SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, UserId FROM UserRecordAccess where RecordId = '068540000000RNq' and UserId ='00554000000Is3Y'`
I get the error

'Can select only RecordId, a Has*Access field, and MaxAccessLevel'

Comment: @User2529 I understood.. What you want to achieve but you cant do that.. Instead Query all users and store in `set<Id>` based on that set query one `userRecordAccess` and then check which user have access or not

Comment: @User2529 still looking for another solution..

Comment: I really appreciate the effort but it's not working. My only issue is I am not able to query the UserIds in userRecordAccess and hence am not able to get the users who have access to that particular record

Comment: @User2529 ohh yes we can't query UserId.. I think you should ask another question with how to query userId in UserRecordAccess  query

Comment: @Ratan, it is not possible :( but I'll ask anyway if someone has found a workaround. Thanks! :)

Comment: @User2529 Yeah sure.. and pls if you find workaround then pls give ans to this( your own question).. So other with same issue will find your ans useful

Comment: @User2529 Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Nope, didn't find any solution for this

Comment: @ratan check it out